# Get squared characters sql-server

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

Here are the characters in database ( last line ) : 
[image]

When I var_dump, the squared characters disapears:
[image]

And I need to get that squared characters.

Comment: What do you mean by "get that squared characters"?

Comment: I mean the squared charaters showed in the table.

Comment: Looks like broken utf8. squared characters never used in real web.

Comment: In php they look like new line characters (i.e. \r\n) which may not be renderable in the grid tool your viewing the data in.  What is the result of `select gdetail, cast(gdetail as varbinary(32)) where gdtlastmod='1484240045'`  (You would see 0d0a for \r\n)

Comment: IF they are coming out of your database fine through one client, but not through another, then it's probably that your other db client isn't set up for UTF8 (or to display whatever this character is if it's just a boring old ascii carriage return and line feed). Like.. it's not your data, it's your tool for viewing your data. No biggie.

Comment: @AlexK. I get " Conversion from text to varbinary is not autorised ". When I try to insert \n it show 4 squars. So I need juste to find which characters correspond to 2 squars.

Comment: @JNevill Certainly. But is there a way to find which characters are showing like 2 squares ?

Comment: @AlexK. It is  " \n " . I add it to the text to insert and it works. Thank to all of you.

Comment: @arshie92 you can add & accept your own answer to your question below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 2 squared characters were finally " \r\n " .